# What is the proper way to get Cloud9 to read lint config files (.jshintrc or .eslintrc)?

Tags: cloud9-ide

I am a new Cloud9 (c9.io) user and I spent the morning searching the web, but cant seem to find an answer on what needs to be done for Cloud9 to recognize me lint config files. They are currently in my workspace/project root, but none of the rules (like, 80 character line max, etc...) are being enforced by the editor. It seems to do some basic linting that I have limited control over... but for javascript development I really need more for my team.

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the Cloud9 IDE uses ESLint for linting purposes within the editor, but doesn't read configuration from `.eslintrc` files within the project yet.

Comment: Thanks. I tried a few things to see if I could get something to work prior to reading this message and its what I concluded as well.

Answer (score 3):

There should be `.eslintrc` parsing support by now in c9 given this patch: https://github.com/c9/c9.ide.language.javascript.eslint/commit/c77d2241d140512b9f807d597e0ccca70bbd8a20

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am glad to hear it supports config files now and I really liked the service. Unfortunately there was just a little too much missing to add it into my development flow at work. I am keeping an eye on the project and continuing to dabble in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

On Cloud9 hosted workspaces, .jslintrc is working. I have just added my own rules after reading [this post](https://community.c9.io/t/writing-a-javascript-app/4964) and it was working well.

It seems to be sufficient to set the rules, that should be changed from the default linting configuration in c9.

Answer (score 0):

*Wanted to make a comment to answer above, but too low on reputation :(*

Seems like eslint config in package.json files (using [eslintConfig field](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring)) is not handled (yet).